# Text_align parameter for questions in jsPsych survey-text plugin

Tags: survey, jspsych

I am using jsPsych Survey-Text plugin (version 7.2) to create a questionnaire. I'd like to align all the questions on the left. What kind of parameters should I add to the codes? Is it possible to change font family/size of the questions? Thank you so much for your time!

Here is my codes & a picture:

var language_questionnaire = {
type: jsPsychSurveyText,
preamble:
" **Language Background Questionnaire**

",
questions: [
{prompt: 'Gender',name:'gender', columns:20, placeholder: 'female, male, others', required: true},
{prompt: 'What country do you currently live in?'}
]
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdgCp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write CSS code directly into your JavaScript code to style the elements:

```
{prompt: '<div style="text-align:left;">What country do you currently live in?</div>'}
```